# Identify INDICES value that 'breaks' by() [or, equivalently, tapply()]

Tags: r, exception, apply, error-logging, tapply

When using the function `by`, at times I will have a data subset (as determined by the `INDICES` argument) that 'breaks' `by` (technically it breaks `FUN` which in turn breaks `by`).

Is there a way to identify the 'bad' value of the list passed to `INDICES`? (without writing an explicit loop over the list)

Comment: The quick and dirty is to just put a `print` statement on entry to `FUN`.

Answer (score 0):

Can you make a reproducible example?

You can try something like,

```
customfun <- function(x)try(somefun(x))
byresult <- by(mydata, mydata$group, FUN=customfun)
whichbad <- sapply(byresult, function(x)which(inherits(x, "try-error")))
```